# Converting PNG design into iOS application view

Tags: ios, ios5

I have pngs which describe very precisely the layout of views that need to be created for an ios application. What is the easiest or smartest way to convert them into ios views? Or is there a best practice methodology which should be followed to create views for them? I also have sliced images available of the components (buttons, text field etc) available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say specifically without seeing what you have, but if you have sliced images:

1) Set the background image of your buttons with the appropriate slices,

2) Use `UIImage` for any other decorative or background artwork.

Hopefully the designer didn't do anything too crazy with tab bars and text fields because you may have to:

3) Subclass some standard UI elements to get what you want. There are detailed tutorials that you can find easily on how to subclass UI elements.

When you edit a XIB in Xcode, you can move things around the screen to set things up without code, so that's easy. If you want to subclass though, you have to write some code.